# Go to line in MATLAB editor

Tags: matlab

How can I **conveniently** jump to a line of an opened file in MATLAB editor?

I'm aware there's [openAndGoToLine](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/476297-how-to-open-m-fiile-in-editor-and-move-to-specific-line-number?s_tid=mwa_osa_a), but I have to type the name of the file (that's in focus) each time, and I'm unsure it works with multiple files having the same name (with the URL's approach). In Python it's within a few keypresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, which brings up the "go to" dialog, where you can type the line number

Enter the number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click OK

[image: goto]

Comment: Surely it makes more sense to use the built-in functionality over writing your own code… :)

Comment: Ok, well, I've briefly looked into this previously and concluded there's no such hotkey. Great.

Comment: props to MATLAB for being an IDE for which such deficit is totally believable...

Answer (score 1):

Combining `openAndGoToLine` with [editor API](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/238561-how-to-find-the-name-of-the-file-that-is-being-edited#comment_307561):

```matlab
ed=matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;matlab.desktop.editor.openAndGoToLine(ed.Filename, 241);
```

Type `ed`, press up arrow - brings up the command. `Left Arrow` twice, `Backspace` as needed, type new line number, `Enter`.

Can replace `ed` with any "trigger" you like. On Windows, `Ctrl + Shift + Left Arrow + Backspace` deletes all of "241".

Comment: You could just define this as a function which takes the line number as an input, then you don't need to faff around with your command history. Edit your `startup` file to ensure it's always on your path